# error message when using pointers c++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#import <iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
int andy = "25";
int andy1 = * andy;
int andyand = & andy;
cout <<"hello"<<endl<<andy<<endl<<andy1<<andyand;
};
```

i am just starting to use pointers in c++ and i can t understand why i'm getting these:
            error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int'
            error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')|
         and
            error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'

Comment: "quotes" specify strings or c char arrays, not ints.

Comment: How did you get this far in C++ without knowing how to include libraries?  You might need to go back 88 MPH and start learning the basics of C++.

Answer (score 3):

First, in C++ you should not use "raw" pointers.

Now, about your problem: error message says: "invalid conversion from const char* to int".

```
int andy = "25";
```

`"25"` is a string literal (with type `const char*`). You want an integer constant instead:

int andy = 25;

Now - `andy` is not a pointer, so you can't apply `*` operator - and this is the reason of your second error (`invalid type argument of unary '*'`).

Finally, read a book, or a tutorial on these, as you're not using pointers anywhere in your code, you're just blindly using `&` and `*` operators.

This could be an example of using pointers:

```
int andy = 25;
int *andy1 = &andy;  // andy1 is the pointer - see star after type declaration
                     // with &andy we're assigning the address of andy variable to it

int andyand = *andy1; // star before pointer is dereferencing - reads the value of the memory
                     // address where pointer is pointing to. So, *andy1 evaluates to 25
cout << "hello" << endl << andy << endl << *andy1 << andyand;
```

Oh, everyone noted this except me - unfortunately (for both you and us), there's no `import` directive in C++ - but [it should be with us in a few years](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/modules-update-on-work-in-progress-doug-gregor).

Comment: +1 for a little tutorial for beginners

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
using namespace std;
main()
{
int andy = 25; // no quotation marks
int* andy1 = &andy; // use "&" to take the addrees of andy for your pointer
int* andyand = & andy;
cout <<"hello"<<endl<<andy<<endl<<andy1<<endl<<andyand;
};
```

There is no need to use quotation marks with the integer variable.

Comment: The line int andy1 = *andy; will still cause an error and thus the line after that as well

Comment: yep, didn't notice that one, I was focused on quotation marks, thanks :-)

Comment: I believe your code still has issues since you're making a conversion from int* to int in your lines:

int andy1 = &andy; and int andyand = &andy;

Comment: Yup, that should now compile!

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of invalid syntax here:

```
#import <iostream> // WRONG!
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int andy = "25"; // Not good
    int andy1 = * andy; // not good
    int andyand = & andy; // not good
    cout <<"hello"<<endl<<andy<<endl<<andy1<<andyand;
}
```

What you should have is:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int andy = 25; // 25 is an int, "25" is a char*
    //int andy1 = *andy; // andy is not a pointer, so you cannot dereference it
    int* andyand = &andy; // andyand now points to andy
    cout <<"hello"<<endl<<andy<<endl<<*andyand;
}
```

Which will print out

```
hello
[value of andy]
[value of andy]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no #import directive in C++. I think you mean

```
#include <iostream>
```

Function main shall have return type int.

Integral literals are specified without quotes. So instead of

```
int andy = "25";
```

should be written

```
int andy = 25;
```

Also these statements

```
int andy1 = * andy;
int andyand = & andy;
```

are invalid. It is not clear what you are trying to define.